# Ошибка 500 The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. (tiles, JSP, Java)

Tags: java, jsp

Пытался прикрутить к простейшему проекту tiles из примера https://o7planning.org/ru/11683/spring-boot-apache-tiles-jsp-tutorial все вроде делал по писанному, за исключением создания проекта, он у меня уже был, в результате HTTP 500. Причем с пояснением что сервер столкнулся с чем-то, что он не может понять :( Хоть бы пояснил с чем...

pom.xml
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=d5e5332a2086f97063fd8af451e7cacb][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/d5e5332a2086f97063fd8af451e7cacb.png[/IMG][/URL]

judiproc-servlet.xml
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=cd2c3f099517aa1005dfec85c347bcb1][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/cd2c3f099517aa1005dfec85c347bcb1.png[/IMG][/URL]

web.xml
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=85a7e59994bc6b044b2da84dc6c92f71][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/85a7e59994bc6b044b2da84dc6c92f71.png[/IMG][/URL]

TilesConfig.java
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=fd9e9e661d921f7c017a8cde422f14af][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/fd9e9e661d921f7c017a8cde422f14af.png[/IMG][/URL]

HomeController.java
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=eae6b776ed600910f50ca22a9600afce][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/eae6b776ed600910f50ca22a9600afce.png[/IMG][/URL]

SpringBootJspTilesApplication.java
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=f031c9bf761d1799077e37bd50d40d80][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/f031c9bf761d1799077e37bd50d40d80.png[/IMG][/URL]

tiles.xml
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=6175a10a91a7e760d82f7d121035abe0][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/6175a10a91a7e760d82f7d121035abe0.png[/IMG][/URL]

Структура проекта
[URL=https: //hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=db78cbc849d36efc22e211f0b91e3cef][IMG]https: //s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2018/08/db78cbc849d36efc22e211f0b91e3cef.png[/IMG][/URL]

Может кто хотя бы на мысль наведет, что не так...

Comment: HomeController.java  https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=9a51bb25d5dd9e0292a03edc151c2f54

Comment: judiproc-servlet.xml      https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=5a27258056aed28820ac5352ad1127b4

Comment: pom.xml     https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=7b1af89486406c79a9a8df0030752384

Comment: SpringBootJspTilesApplication.java     https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=832c685a6b87952657bf647e0eddfa40

Comment: Структура проекта:     https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=1e5c1a97b3caba9911971a9d6801ffcd

Comment: tiles.xml     https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=1c601c20c2a740ddcfc3180367c9f315

Comment: tilesConfig.java     https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=ab4c5e646e1db1cf1d749e13693f95c2

Comment: web.xml     https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=c3b3a4ad7383ea6141d19b57e88704a9

Comment: Напишите конкретную проблему, с которой вы сталкиваетесь. Если у вас много проблем, то пытайтесь посетить по одной в каждом вопросе.

Comment: @BorodaOleg, приведите код в текстовом виде а не в виде скриншотов